# Where does grub-install take the arguments for grub-mkimage from?

Tags: grub, btrfs, mbr

When I run `grub-install /dev/vda -v` I see this line in the output:

```
grub-mkimage --directory '/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc' --prefix '(,msdos1)/boot/grub' --output '/boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img'  --dtb '' --format 'i386-pc' --compression 'auto'  'ext2' 'part_msdos' 'biosdisk'
```

How do I configure GRUB to add specific modules in the list of `grub-mkimage` arguments?

Backstory: I am trying to migrate a BIOS/MBR installation of PureOS from ext4 to btrfs, so I need to add btrfs module to the GRUB image before running `grub-install`.
The instruction [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Btrfs%20migration) is nice but it is for UEFI/GPT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're asking for the information available in the [man pages](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-grub-install/) of `grub-install`:

```
       -d, --directory=DIR
              use images and modules under DIR [default=/usr/lib/grub/<platform>]
...
       --modules=MODULES
              pre-load specified modules MODULES
```

So you can use `--modules=btrfs` on your grub-install command to add this module.

The default modules are checked by the `grub-install` tool itself by looking at the system and gathering the important information (such as the fs type).